# custom page allowing verification of existing item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

The scenario is that I need a multi stage pages. Ideally I would like to do this on a single page but for simplicity 2 pages are fine.
On the 1st page I need to verify if an item exists in the contacts list. The process is to enter a name in a text box then two lower sections show the email and phone number of the person automatically.

So if I type Sam, the I see all entries starting with Sam or even a drop down list. Once selection made, two fields below are then automatically populated with persons email and phone.
When the correct user is selected the next button will pass the ID to another page for further processing. I need then to create an item in a different list.

I think the way forward is client side coding (JSOM), dont want to use SPD unless it has a clear advantage.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at using the REST API to pull your contact data, filter/display/process with JavaScript, and then the REST API again to create the subsequent list item? This should allow you to perform the whole process in one page. Rest API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx

Comment: Hi I hope you can provide some clarity for me. I've used webservices in the past but not in code. In my post I mention JSOM - Is this the client object model with javascript? I assume Rest is a webservice, how about Soap (does this apply to SharePoint also)?
How can I add REST code into sharepoint, does it go in a CEWP? or will I need to create a ASPX page via SPD?
Thanks